# How to compile a snippet of code conditionally only if the application is not a Console one?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, c-preprocessor

I tried to search for a #define/#const default list (such as DEBUG and TRACE) with but found nothing on the internet...

I have a source file for generic helper methods (utility ones like custom operators, extensions to work with strings, to popup a form with a property grid editor and so on) that is shared (using Add Existing Item -> Link) between multiple projects.

Some of the functions defined are relative to WinForms and this causes the compiler to complain about it, when building Console projects because of the missing reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Is there any #Const or #define that tells the current application type(`<MyType>WindowsForms</MyType>`)?
I do not want to split it in two files so I am looking for some workaround that doesn't involve the creation of a class library, the referencing of winforms from console, and the definition of a constant for every project (this because i feel bad at not being able to somehow use the already specified application type in the project properties).

I think this problem could be generalized to:

*(How) can I determine if an assembly\namespace is referenced in the project at compile time in order to apply conditional compilation?*

Comment: Unreferenced form? What do you mean by this? You have either a form or not, where is the problem?

Comment: @beppe9000 While it is a valid question, I 1. doubt that such defines exist 2. [Not sure that it is what your really need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you elaborate in a more detailed way about the actual issue you face and the result you want to achieve?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I enhanced the question

Answer (score 5):

This would be an abuse of conditional compilation. It's really for various configurations or platform targeting, not for splitting up code.

Split out your code into two libraries, one core library (for both console/WinForms) and another that is related to WinForms only. You don't require conditional compilation here. You need to organize your code to be more modular for your application development demands. Then your console applications can use the core library and your WinForms applications can use both.

Comment: Ditto - I used a WinForm app for a similar task. I detect in the Load event if I need to show the form or just execute the code to perform a task. If I don't need the form I just exit the program before I leave the Load event. More like conditional execution than conditional compilation.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a huge design-flaw. In particular you should have some separation of view and model. This means while there is one assembly that holds and provides access to your data (the so called model) there are two different projects where you handle all the UI-stuff - one console-application and one WinForms-application. Now both those executables reference your model-assembly. Thus the model is completely independent from if the actual program runs in a console or not as it simply provides data.

This principle is also called [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Its about separate every aspect (e.g. data-access, UI) into different places, in your case even different assemblies.

EDIT:

> I do not want to split it in two files so I am looking for some workaround that doesn't involve the creation of a class library, the referencing of winforms from console, and the definition of a constant for every project (this because i feel bad at not being able to somehow use the already specified application type in the project properties).

I think you have some broken image of how OOP works and what assemblies are for. Basically an assemlby is a collection of objects that serve a particular purpose that **all those objects have in common**. So there is **no need for an assembly to do both processing and displaying at once**. The processing-layer doesn´t need to know anything of your presentation-layers, and thus you won´t need to reference WinForms from your console-application. You console-application and your winforms-application should do more or less the same: **display information**. How this information is created doesn´t serve the purpose for those two and should be **completely sperated away**.

Let´s illustrate what we got so far on an example. You have your three assemblies, namely `DataProcessing`, `ConsoleApp`, and `WinFormsApp`. Within the first you have some code that gets data from a datasource:

```
class Retriever 
{
    public List<int> GetData() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Now in both your consuming apps you have the code for display:

```
using DataProcessing;  // no WinForms-stuff

class ConsoleApp
{
    static void Main(params int[] args) 
    {
        var r = new Retriever();
        var data = r.GetData();

        foreach(var i in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The third assembly has code for winforms:

```
using DataProcessing;  // no console-stuff
using Microsoft.Win32;

class WinFormsApp : Forms
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var r = new Retriever();
        var data = r.GetData();

        foreach(var in in data)
        {
            myLabel.Text += i;
        }
    }
}
```

All you have to do is reference `DataProcessing`-assembly within your two apps, no need for any definition of further constants. Simply execute the app you want to and they automatically will call the code from the referenced assembly. Now the reference to Winforms only exists in the actual winforms-application, not in the two other assemblies. As you see the two assemblies `ConsoleApp` and `WinFormsApp` do not have much in common, so why should they reside in the same assembly at all?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to define "conditional compilation symbols" (= #define) in the Build tab of the Project Properties.

Comment: I would like to derive that information from the setting (<MyType>WindowsForms</MyType>) in the project properties.